# Scheduling an email report in Marketing Cloud/ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have just started using Marketing Cloud and I want to set up some sort of automation which sends the report for an email after 7 working days. So far I haven't found a way, and using Automation Studio or Journey Builder just confounds me, as when trying to specify a trigger it is asking for specific data extensions or for a file to appear in a specified folder, neither of which are relevant to what I want to do.

I want something along the lines of

> 'whenever an email is sent where the name contains "yourstringhere"
>   send an email/notification to xyz@xyzyz.com'

Can anyone help?

Comment: What name is this 'yourstringhere' ? Email name ?

Comment: Hi @ManeeshGupta, yes it would be in the email name.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest to implement for send time notifications is to have a script (AMP or SSJS) inside the email.  Here you can create an if statement to match the Email name or whatever variable you want and then trigger either an [upsert to a DE](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/UpsertData.html) or a [triggered email send](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/creating_a_triggered_send_using_ampscript_and_the_web_service_api/) (or even a trigger a full automation if you want to run multiple steps).

If you only want it sent once per email, make sure to set the if statement to contain [`if _JobSubscriberBatchID == 1 then`](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/) so that the script only runs once per job and not for each recipient.

This would mean the script would have to be included in EVERY email you want notifications from though, which can become unwieldy quickly.  You may want to look into having this put into a header/footer content area and use it inside a specific delivery profile to help reduce manual insertion needs.

Comment: @Gortington this is a fantastic solution. I'm going to implement this just because it's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Query on _Job data view. It has email name column. Filter on Email Name and store the results in a Data Extension. Rows existing in this Data Extension will indicate that such email was sent.
You can then use this data extension in Journey and send email.
Automation Program can be used to automate all of it. Hope it helps